# Is there a way to morph all larvae at once?

Tags: starcraft-2

My macro is pretty poor, and while playing the HotS campaign, I often find myself in cases where my larvae are simply idling. When I've built multiple hatcheries, with the campaign-specific 6-larvae cap, I often find myself with bunches of 12+ larvae.

Trying to turn these larvae into combat-ready units is irritating, as I need to press the appropriate button once *per larvae*. I know that in Starcraft the First, selected Larvae all morphed at once, resource permitting.

Is there a similar method to morph groups of larvae in Starcraft 2?

Comment: You could always group all your hatcheries to the zero number key, then just "select all larvae" on all your hatcheries at once c:

Comment: @user1337 The issue isn't with selecting larvae (I can do that fine :P ), but rather, getting the larvae to turn into something else, which requires one key press per larvae.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is quite simple once you know how.

1. Put all your hatcheries in a control group.
2. Press that control group to select all your hatcheries
3. Press "s" on your keyboard (that will select all your larve from all your selected hatcheries).
4. Press the kotkey for that unit (ie: "Z" is for zergling, "H" is for hydra, etc.), hold it down, it will then start making a lot of that unit real fast after a small delay. Release when you are satisfied or when you are out of larvae.

To do this though, you need to use the hotkeys and not click on the icons. It is the fastest, less apm consuming way to create units with larvae.

Comment: The delay in point 4 coincides with the keyboard speed settings in the control panel. Both the delay in holding down the key and how fast the repeat rate is executed.

Comment: did not knew that, nice to know, mine is setted at a good delay, barely a fraction of second of holding down.

Comment: My fellow master league player told me that all hatcheries in ctrl+1 is must have.

Comment: in which control group you place them is really up to preferences though. I like to put my army on 1-2-3 and my buildings on 4-5-6.